# Create dot map in R

Tags: r

I would like to create a dot map in R.

I have a shapefile called shp:

And a csv file called sch

and a water shapefile called water_shp

I gave  that code

```
map <- inner_join(sch,shp,by="Region")
map = st_as_sf(map)


tm_shape(map) +
  tm_borders("grey", lwd = 1.25)  +
  tm_fill("ratio",style = "cont", legend.reverse = TRUE, title = "fertility ratio")
```

But I can not add dot points  in the map, which show the size of SEP? How can  I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `nc` sample data:

```
library(tmap)
library(sf)
example(st_read)
```

I think what you are trying to do is fill according to one attribute and then scale a dot based on another attribute. Use `tm_bubbles` for the dots:

```
tm_shape(nc) + tm_fill("NWBIR74") +  tm_bubbles(size="SID79")
```

[image]